# EditableViews without a table?

Tags: 7, views

I'm looking for the features of the editable views module without having to use a table (In Drupal 7).

I have a view that I use as an input form. I'm using the "editable views" module to expose those fields as editable. However, I would like to customize this beyond what a Table will provide. There's some CSS trickery I can do (e.g. moving cells around with CSS), but that seems very hackish. Are there any modules/methods out there to do what I'm trying to do?

(example)

I have...

```
 | Title | Description | Author | Feedback (Editable) | Rating (Editable)
```

I want...

```
 Title, Author
 Description
 Feedback (Editable) | Rating (Editable)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution!

A patch is in the works to provide this exact functionality.

Patch: https://www.drupal.org/node/2579113

Installation:

1. go to your /sites/all/modules/editableviews directory
2. wget [get the patch file link]
3. run `patch < editableviews-style-unformatted-2579113-26.patch`

Setup:

1. Clear Cache (I used the dev module's clear cache functionality)
2. Edit your view
3. Change your View Format:Format to be "Editable Unformatted"
4. Change your View Format:Show to be "Fields"

When you save/preview, all your fields will be in <span> tags that you can customize in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EditableFields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields) instead, which will let you use `Unformatted list` instead of `table`.

> This module allows CCK fields to be edited on a node's display (e.g.
>   at node/123), not just on the node edit pages (e.g. node/123/edit). It
>   **also works within views** etc. Anywhere a 'formatter' can be selected,
>   you can select editable (or click to edit).

[image]

- Here is a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jf_2e_RYS2M) on how to use it.

Then you can use CSS to get the view to look how you want it.

```
.field-title { float: left; }
.field-feedback { float: left; }
```

Also, you will probably need to resize the edit button.

---

Else, if you do not want to use CSS then the following may possibly work:

1) Hide all your fields from display

2) In FIELDS, add a Global: Custom field

3) Use the replacement patterns on your custom field.

Ex:

```
[title], [author] <br>
[field_description] <br>
[field_feedback] | [field_rating]
```

Comment: Yeah; I don't like the functionality/appearance of the EditableFields module (seems a bit clunky). BUT, the idea of hiding the fields from view and re-adding them by token sounds pretty awesome! I'll have to give that a shot!